# On entry to SGEMM parameter number 15 had an illegal value

Tags: c++, cublas

I am trying to use cublasSgemmStridedBatched to multiply a block diagonal matrix by another matrix.

I want to perform C= B^T * A

where B is block diagonal and so it's stored in memory with the blocks stacked on top of each other ( the off-diagonal blocks are not stored at all)

The error I got was:
Check failed: status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)  CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE

** On entry to SGEMM  parameter number 15 had an illegal value

Here is the function call:

```
CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasSgemmStridedBatched(handle, cuTransB, cuTransA, N, M, K, &alpha, B, ldb, strideB, A, lda, strideA, &beta, C, ldc, strideC, num_blocks));
```

Here are some print outs:

```
cuTransB = 1 has type 17cublasOperation_t
cuTransA = 0 has type 17cublasOperation_t
N = 5 has type i
M = 100 has type i
K = 8 has type i
alpha = 1 has type f
B = 0x701164000 has type PKf, has dimensions 800 by 5 in memory
B^T block has dimensions 5 by 8
ldb = 800 has type i
strideB = 8 has type x
A = 0x7012aca00 has type PKf, has dimensions 800 by 100 in memory
A block has dimensions 8 by 100
lda = 800 has type i
strideA = 8 has type x
beta = 0 has type f
C = 0x701b60000 has type Pf, has dimensions 500 by 100 in memory
C block has dimensions 5 by 100
ldc = 500 has type i
strideC = 5 has type x
num_blocks = 100 has type i
```

So the function call was really:

```
CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasSgemmStridedBatched(handle, 1, 0, 5, 100, 8, 0x7fff58eb69e4, 0x701164000, 800, 8, 0x7012aca00, 800, 8, 0x7fff58eb69e0, 0x701b60000, 500, 5, 100));
```

I'm not sure what the 15th parameter of SGEMM is - I don't think this function is open source? I'm quite confused.

What may or may not be important to notice is that strideB < ldb. That is, the B blocks are mixed in memory. As I mentioned I initialized B as a 800 by 5 matrix and I am considering the 100 8 by 5 blocks.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: (edit) Reformatted code

Answer (score 2):

This is because the implementation logic of cublasSgemmStridedBatched in different cuda versions is different.
In cuda 9, the C cann't be separated by column, which means strideC must greater or equal to the size of C block.
In cuda 10+, it works. You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like

```
CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasSgemmStridedBatched(Caffe::cublas_handle(), cuTransB, cuTransA, 5, 5, 5,&alpha, B, 5, 24, A, 5, 25, &beta, C, 5, ANYTHING_LESS_THAN_25, num_blocks));
```

Will throw the same error. I suspect they're trying to prevent collision when writing to C so I think, even though there would be no collision in my above case because I'm describing the separate horizontal 5 by 100 strips of C, the error is caused because:

strideC = 5 < 5 * 100 = size of C block

I think the C blocks cannot be mixed in memory.